# How to implement this algorithm without mutation

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to implement the following algorithm in a functional language using immutability, higher-order functions and/or recursion (no loops or mutation).

The algorithm iterates a list, and for each pair of adjacent elements, swaps them if the left is larger than the right.

However, if the difference between two adjacent elements are less than some number (say `10`), a function (`notify`) should be called with these as arguments

Any tips on how I can rewrite it?

```
for (i = 1, i < queue.legth, i++) {
  left = queue[i-1]
  right = queue[i]

  if (abs(left - right) < 10) {
    notify(left, right)
  } else if (left > right) {
    queue[i-1] = right
    queue[i] = left
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Yes, instead of mutating the list in place, a new list should be returned

Comment: what do you mean "*without mutation*"?

Comment: does a `forEach`, or `reduce` count as mutation?

Comment: _"(no loops or mutation)"_ Is recursion aloowed ?

Comment: The very idea of 'swapping' inside an array implies mutation. I think you want a function that returns a new array with swapped elements when they match that scenario

Comment: @Sergio this is correct

Comment: @Tarlen _"Yes, instead of mutating the list in place, a new list should be returned"_ Should new list contain both swapped items and items which were not swapped ? Or, only swapped items from original array ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with elixir?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a horrible language for this.  But here is the idea.

First implement linked lists.  Your API could include the following commands:

```
var empty_list = create_empty_list()
var larger_list = list.prepend(thing)
var is_empty = list.is_empty()
var first_element = list.head()
var tail = list.tail()
var reversed_list = list.reversed()
```

Internally a linked list is just an object with a head, and another object pointing to the tail.  So prepending to the list just means creating a new node with a new value pointing to the old one.  (ie Not a mutation!)  So you've got accessors.  And then `reversed` is a straightforward recursive function.  (You need a helper function `list._reversed(tail)` and then `list.reversed()` is just `list._reversed(create_empty_list())`.  The helper function returns `tail` for the empty list, and otherwise returns `this.tail._reversed(tail.prepend(this.head))`.)

With a linked list, you can iterate over the queue, building the rearranged list and calling `notify` where you want.  When you are done iterating over the queue, then you have a linked list exactly backwards.  However then you call `reversed` to get the queue in the right order.